# data structure association list - how to create head key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have a question about a data structure association list / a singly-linked list which only adds to the head.
The set function is suppose to set (multiple) key-value pairs and the get function should get those pairs- I dont understand how to make the head (which is suppose to be null at first)
to be an object and since the newly create node becomes the 'new' head - I dont understand how I can 'move' the 'old' head with its key value pairs..
Happy about any help! Thank you!

This is my code(not much but don't know how to go from here at all)

```
function List () {
 this.head=null;
}

function ListN (key, value, next) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
  this.next = next;
}
Alist.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
  // this.key=value;
  var newNode=new ListN(key, value);
  this.head=newNode;
};

Alist.prototype.get = function (key) {
  return this.key;
};

smallList = new List();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You missed a previous node in the call of new ListN.

```
var newNode = new ListN(key, value, this.head);
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
function List() {
    this.head = null;
}

List.prototype.set = function (key, value) {

    function ListN(key, value, next) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    var node = this.head;
    while (node) {
        if (node.key === key) {
            node.value = value;
            return;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
    this.head = new ListN(key, value, this.head);
};

List.prototype.get = function (key) {
    var node = this.head;
    while (node) {
        if (node.key === key) {
            return node.value;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
};

var smallList = new List();

smallList.set('one', 'abc');
console.log(smallList);
smallList.set('two', 'def');
console.log(smallList);

console.log(smallList.get('one'));
console.log(smallList.get('two'));
console.log(smallList.get('three')); 

smallList.set('two', 'xyz');
console.log(smallList);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina! Now setting multiple key value pairs works, but not getting them. Also setting/getting one (not multiple) key value pairs doesn't work- don't know why but I get undefined..

Comment: Thanks a lot-it all works now. So what happens here (I am learning data structures so just trying to understand it) is that first the head is being 'created' using the new keyword, then we ask if head is null or was created (=has value), if so we ask if it the same key and if yes we return and then move the head by setting it to be next - is this correct? Also, we need to return the head, otherwise, if we did set the head to be next and didn't remove the 'previous one ' it would sort of get lost?

Comment: right. but one problem exits, you get only the first value with the same key. for updating or creating, you have to search for it first, to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

in a key value object you should always have one key so use KISS principle:

```
var object = {};

object['aKey'] = 'some value';
object['otherKey] = 'other value';
```

If what you want is to store objects, use an array:

```
var myArray = [];

myArrray.push({'key': 'value'});
myArrray.push({'key': 'value'});
myArrray.push({'key1': 'value1'});
```

if you want a lot of values for one key:

```
var object = {};

if(!object.hasOwnProperty('aKey')){
  object['aKey'] = [];
}

object['aKey'].push('value');
```

Javascript is simple, so keep it simple :)

Comment: its an exercise about data structure association list so I can't just use js like I would do otherwise.